# Не работают media query в IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Верстка mobile first, поэтому грузятся только мобильные стили.
Отчего-то не работают media в 9ке, что сделано:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

```
@import "concat-less/bem.mobile.less";
// 600+
@media (min-width: 600px) {
   @import "concat-less/bem.tablet.less";
}
// 960px and (not handheld) - десктопы (4 колонки)
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    @import "concat-less/bem.desktop.min.less";
}
// 1025px - планшеты и десктопы (4 колонки)
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    @import "concat-less/bem.desktop.less";
}
// максимальная ширина контейнера 1280
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    @import "concat-less/bem.desktop.big.less";
}
```

В эмуляторе IE 9 в IE 11 все хорошо, но в реальном IE 9 все плохо.
В чём причина проблемы?

Comment: а почему импорт делается для `.less`, а не `.css`-файлов?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko затем все компилируется в css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге что было сделано:
Для IE компилируется отдельный файл со стилями, без media и без мобильной версии. Почему не работают, так и осталось загадкой. Везде пишут, что ИЕ9 поддерживает.

**UPD!!**
IE не поддерживает больше 4096 селекторов в стилях.
Стили для IE разбиваются на отдельные css.